# WHERE Clause In Embedded SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    a calculation here
FROM
(
    three different Selects in here, all UNIONed together
) foo
```

What is the syntax to add a WHERE clause to the outermost SELECT?

Using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: just after your `foo` you can write `WHERE foo.Column = ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `WHERE` clause after outer `foo` subquery alias :

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM ( <union query here> 
     ) foo
WHERE foo.col . . .
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - perfect!